# Change language and layout of iPhone app

Tags: ios, ipad, localization, multilingual

I'm wondering if there is a best practices for changing the app language and change the layout of the app when click a `UIButton`, let's say change a `UITabBarItem` order, strings, buttons, textfield, etc... places depends on the selected language.

I know about apple Localized, but it's for strings.

I've think about create a nib file for each language, but i don't know if it's the best practices solution.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/internationalization/

Comment: thank you, i've checked it before, they talked about change a text, not a layout.

Comment: That link will lead you to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LocalizingInterfaces.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002138-BBCBFFDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NIB's can be localized too - as people have pointed out in the comments, it's all in the documentation. Here's a link to a tutorial that may also be of help:

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/09/tutorial-iphone-localization-in-xib-nib-files/